# How do I download contents into an NSData using a Secure URL?

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I'm starting with the following snip to download an image

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *url = @"https://...";
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:url] options:nil error:&error];
```

When this code runs, the error instance contains an error without a whole lot of information in the userInfo. It's just the secure url that was attempted.

Given the results, I'm pretty sure these methods don't handle secure URLs.

My question:

> Is there an easy way (like these
>   methods, or some option) to set the
>   ***dataWithContentsOfURL:*** method to download over a secure url?

Comment: iPhone SDK is quite fussy about HTTPS certificates, and would fail if the server isn't using a verified certificate.

Comment: https URLs should work just fine. What is the error?

Comment: The error looks like this (server and path altered):
Error: {
    NSURL = https://server.com/..../6011861.jpg;
}

Comment: There's more to an NSError object than just the userInfo. You need to look at the entire thing.

Comment: NSLogged error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 UserInfo=0x11a560 "Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 256.). What is a 256 error code? where can I look this up in the future?

Comment: Looking in FoundationErrors.h:
    NSFileReadUnknownError = 256,                           // Read error (reason unknown)

Comment: 256 is NSFileReadUnknownError in that domain. Your URL is probably malformed.

Comment: Arg. Looks like the Server Certificate is bad :( Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running your URL through [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) first

Comment: Turns out the server cert is invalid. Oddly, safari didn't show a warning. It was only after loading the URL in firefox did I get a message with the invalid cert and details. Giving you the credit for the help though, thanks.